# PHP - How can I parse the JSON data in fetched SQL data?

Tags: php

I have a table and php script. I want to fetch all datas (with PDOStatement->fetchAll() expression). I can do it. But there is a JSON column among my columns in the table. When I fetch this, the JSON data fetching as text format. I want to this JSON data be an array.

For example:

I can fetch that;

Array
(
[ID] => 1
[name] => Example
[json] => [1,2,3]
)

But I want to this;

Array
(
[ID] => 1
[name] => Example
[json] => Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
)
)

So I need the parse the JSON data when fetch the SQL query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[json] => [1,2,3]` - this is array

and this also

```
[json] => Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
)
)
```

If you use Mysql write that
[Json in Mysql](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/working-with-mysql-json-data-type-with-prepared-statements-using-it-in-go-and-resolving-the-15ef14974c48)

When You  fetch this in php You can

```
$res = your query to DB
foreach($res as &$r)
{
  $r = json_decode($r['json']) 
}
```

Example

```
$a[]['json'] = '{"name":"John1","age":31,"city":"New York"}';
$a[]['json'] = '{"name":"John2","age":31,"city":"New York"}';


foreach($a as &$r) 
{
    $r = json_decode($r['json']);
}
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: I got it. This is not what I wanted. I should do this process in query. I should see this array in the result I got from the query.

Comment: It is well described here https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/